# Compartilhando conteúdo de aplicativo feito em Intel XDK no Facebook

Tags: javascript, html5, facebook

Olá!

Eu criei um aplicativo em HTML5 + JQuery Mobile no Intel XDK, que será para android (e quem sabe app para FB). Nele, baseado em dados, tem uma espécie de pontuação (ele não é um jogo) e queria colocar uma opção para compartilhar essa pontuação no Facebook. Já tentei ler as referencias do Facebook sobre isso, mas não entendi.

Desde já, obrigado.